# Split Values In Column & Put On New Row With Same Number In Another Column

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with two columns: PRODUCT ID and CATEGORIES.  There is only one number in the PRODUCT ID column but in the CATEGORIES column there can be multiple numbers separated by commas.  What I need is for the numbers separated by commas to go on to new rows but keep the same PRODUCT ID.  Here's an example;

What it looks like now:

```
PRODUCT ID   |   CATEGORIES
1            |   76,81
2            |   76,78
3            |   76,80
```

What I need:

```
PRODUCT ID   |   CATEGORIES
1            |   76
1            |   81
2            |   76
2            |   78
3            |   76
3            |   80
```

How can I do this in excel, I need a formula to do this.  I have about 6000 products so doing this manually is not an option.

Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry yes, some may have 3 or 4 in, it does differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim ID As Variant
    Dim arrCategories() As String

    Dim d As Range
    Set d = Range("D1")

    Dim i As Long

    For Each c In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))

        ID = c.Value
        arrCategories() = Split(c.Offset(0, 1).Text, ",")

        For i = LBound(arrCategories) To UBound(arrCategories)

            d.Value = ID
            d.Offset(0, 1).Value = arrCategories(i)

            Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)

        Next i

    Next c

End Sub
```

The input data must be in columns A:B starting in row 1.

The output will be written in columns D:E starting in row 1.

Best regards,

Simon